# Where to find Remote debugger for visual studio 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I want to start a Remote Debugger on Remote machine, but I didn't find any source for remote debugger installation files.

Where can I find Remote debugger for visual studio 2005?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio %Ver% \Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have VS2010 installed at the moment. For 2010, the remote debugger is located in `Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\`. You can pick the flavour you need. I imagine VS2005 should have it in the same general location. There is no need to install the debugger. Just copy it to the machine you want to debug and run it. You may need to run it as admin and configure some access settings.